# How can I stop Ubuntu Pro ad from showing up in apt system command?

Tags: apt, 20.04, adblock

Ubuntu is showing ads in system commands. How can I stop this?

I am aware of "upgrade OS to something that is not adware" as a solution.

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  vlc-bin vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58 librpmsign8 python2.7-dev
  exo-utils libmagick++-6.q16-8 libavfilter7 vlc-plugin-svg rpm2cpio
  libimage-magick-perl libwireshark13 liburiparser-dev ffmpeg libwsutil11
  liburiparser1 vlc-plugin-samba libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra
  libimage-magick-q16-perl imagemagick libmaven3-core-java libswresample3
  vlc-plugin-qt libopenexr-dev php-symfony-expression-language libgegl-0.4-0
  librpmbuild8 lynx-common libzmq5 python2.7-minimal libhdf5-103
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libwiretap10 vlc-plugin-skins2 libgegl-common
  vlc-plugin-visualization vlc-l10n libcgraph6 libpython2.7 debugedit
  python2.7 libmagickwand-6-headers vlc-plugin-notify libvlc5 libpython2.7-dev
  libexo-2-0 libhdf5-dev lynx libzmq3-dev libpostproc55 liblab-gamut1
  libvlccore9 libvlc-bin phpmyadmin librpmio8 wireshark hdf5-helpers libpmix2
  imagemagick-6.q16 rpm-common wireshark-common maven libmagickcore-6-headers
  rpm librpm8 libhdf5-cpp-103 cpanminus tor libavcodec58 libexo-common
  vlc-plugin-access-extra libmagickcore-6-arch-config vlc libcdt5 libavutil56
  vlc-data python3-jupyter-core php-twig libpathplan4 libavdevice58
  libmagickwand-6.q16-dev libswscale5 libgvpr2 libopenexr24 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libmysofa1 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-video-splitter tor-geoipdb
  libpython2.7-minimal php-symfony-cache libmagickwand-dev libwireshark-data
  php-symfony-var-exporter libgvc6 vlc-plugin-base libpython2.7-stdlib
  traceroute python3-scipy libmagickcore-6.q16-dev graphviz libavresample4
  libmagickcore-dev wireshark-qt libexo-helpers imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
```